# Replace a match in a text (including /../)

Tags: sed

I am using the following command to find .js file names from an HTML.

```
jsFiles=$(echo "$BODY" | sed -rn 's/<script\s.*src=\W(.*.js).*/\1/p')
```

Sample input:

```
 <script src="a.js"></script> 
 <script src="b.js"></script> 
 <script src="c.js"></script> 
 <script src="d.js"></script>
```

Sample output:

```
a.js
b.js
c.js
d.js
```

Now, I want to replace the found file names in HTML.

Sample output:

```
 <script src="http://10.122.96.13./a.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://10.122.96.13./b.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://10.122.96.13./c.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://10.122.96.13./d.js"></script>
```

I have tried the following but didn't work..

```
for fn in $jsFiles; do
 BODY=$(echo "$BODY" | sed  's/'$fn'/http://10.122.96.13/'$fn'/g')      
done
```

Comment: don't use sed to parse html: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3784644. Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/113 for how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's#[a-zA-Z]\.js#http://10.122.96.13./&#'  Input_file
```